# Rails 4.2 階層を持った URL の静的ページを1つのコントローラーでルーティングしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails のルーティングについてです。
複数の半静的ページを1つのコントローラーで制御しようとしています。
config/routes.rb に全ページ分 get メソッドを書くのも辛いので、下記のように書きました。

```
  StaticPagesController.action_methods.each do |action|
    match action,
      action: action,
      controller: :static_pages,
      via: :get,
      as: action
  end
```

しかし、これでは階層を持った URL に対応できません。(example.com/foo/bar)
1つ1つ get 'foo/bar' => 'static_pages#bar' のように書く以外に解決法はないでしょうか。
完全に初心者なので「ない」もしくは「設計上好ましくない」ということだけでも確認したいです。

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

---

追記

StaticPagesController で、
example.com/page1 と、
example.com/foo/page2 と、
example.com/foo/bar/page3 の
全アクションを書くのが目的です。
コントローラーのコードは下記のようなイメージです。

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def page1
  end

  def page2
  end

  def page3
  end
end
```

ただし、できることなら

```
get 'page1' => 'static_pages#page1', 
get 'foo/page2' => 'static_pages#page2', 
get 'foo/bar/page3' => 'static_pages#page3'
```

と一つずつ書くのは避けたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Railsの Route Globbing を使ってはいかがでしょうか？

参考サイト
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

#### Route Globbingの例

config/routes.rb

```
get '*path', to: 'pages#show'
```

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @path = params[:path]
    end
end
```

app/views/pages/show.html.erb

```
<%= @path %>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。当方、完全にど素人で大変恐縮なのですが、この場合、page1.html.erb, page2.html.erb といった View ファイルを分けるには、どのように致せば良いでしょうか。

Comment: コントローラで、render params[:path] として、対応するビューを作成しておきます。

Comment: 早速試してみたのですが、コントローラーの page1 メソッドが呼ばれません。render params[:path] を show メソッドに置くと、対応の View は表示されますが、階層を持った URL には対応できない状況です。path には "foo/bar"のように入ってきてはいるのですが。。

Comment: 上記のRoute Globbing の例の場合、全てのルートパスが PagesController の showメソッドに入ってきます。page1とかpage2とかのメソッドを作っても呼ばれません。

この場合、showメソッドの中で、render params[:path] を使って、様々なパスに応じた静的ページのビューを表示することになります。

render "foo" の場合は、app/views/pages/foo.html.erbを表示しますが、render "foo/bar" の場合は、app/views/foo/bar.html.erbを表示します。後者は app/views/pages ディレクトリ以下にビューを作成するのではないので注意してください。

参考サイトもちゃんと読んでくださいね。ググれば日本語のサイトも出てきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「後者は app/views/pages ディレクトリ以下にビューを作成するのではないので注意してください。」の部分にて解決致しました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。